# C++ user input not registering

Tags: c++

I am just beginning to learn C++ but I am having trouble spotting the error. When I compile my code, it seems it cannot get past the first two if statements. Once the statements within the if statements appear on the compiler screen, the program suddenly stops. I am trying to figure out why I cannot input in the `std::cin >>` parts despite the code showing no errors on the compiler. If anyone could help me figure this out, it would greatly be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...

    std::string internetPlan;
    float monthlyBill;
    float internetPlanA = 9.95;
    float internetPlanB = 13.95;
    float internetPlanC = 29.99;
    float amountSaved1; //amount saved comparing plan A to plan B
    float amountSaved2; // amount saved comparing plan A to plan C
    float amountSaved3; //amount saved comparing plan B to plan C
    std::string months[12] = {"January", "February",  "March", "Abril", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
    std::string userInput;
    int hoursOfMonth;
    std::cout << "Welcome to the Ardeo Internet Service Provider\n";
    std::cout << "The following are our internet service plans\n";
    std::cout << "Package A: $9.95 per month for 10 hours access. Additional hours are $2.00 per hour\n";
    std::cout << "Package B: $13.95 per month for 20 hours access. Additional hours are $1.00 per hour\n";
    std::cout << "Package C: $29.99 per month per unlimited access\n";

    std::cout << "Please enter your internet plan. Enter A, B or C";
    std::cin >> internetPlan;
    if (internetPlan!= "A" || internetPlan!="a" || internetPlan != "B" || internetPlan!= "b" || internetPlan != "C" || internetPlan != "c") {
        std::cout << "Please enter a valid plan\n";
        std::cout << "Enter plan A, B or C\n";
        std::cin >> internetPlan;
    }

    std::cout << "Please enter the hours you used\n";
    std::cin >> hoursOfMonth;
    if (hoursOfMonth < 0 || hoursOfMonth > 744) {
        std::cout << "You cannot have negative hours or more than 744\n";
        std::cout << "Please enter the hours again\n";
        std::cin >> hoursOfMonth;
        return hoursOfMonth;
    }


    std::cout << "Please enter the month";
    std::cin >> userInput;

    if (userInput == months[0] && hoursOfMonth > 744) {
        std::cout << "Sorry you have too many hours for the month of Janurary\n";
        std::cout << "Please enter month again";
        std::cin>> userInput;
    } else if (userInput == months[1] && hoursOfMonth > 672){
        std::cout << "Sorry too many hours for Februrary\n";
        std::cout << "Please enter month again";
        std::cin>> userInput;
    } else if (userInput == months[2] && hoursOfMonth > 744) {
        std::cout << "Sorry too many hours for March\n";
        std::cout << "Please enter month again";
        std::cin >> userInput;
    } else if (userInput == months[3] && hoursOfMonth > 720) {
        std::cout << "Sorry too many hours for Abril\n";
        std::cout << "Please enter month again";
        std::cin>> userInput;
    } else if (userInput == months[4] && hoursOfMonth > 744) {
        std::cout << "Sorry too many hours for May\n";
        std::cout << "Please enter month again";
        std::cin >> userInput;
    } else if ( userInput == months[5] && hoursOfMonth > 720) {
        std::cout << "Sorry too many hours for June\n";
        std::cout << "Please enter month again";
        std::cin>> userInput;
    } else if (userInput == months[6] && hoursOfMonth > 744){
        std::cout << "Sorry too many hours for July\n";
        std::cout << "Please enter month again";
        std::cin>> userInput;
    } else if (userInput == months[7] && hoursOfMonth > 744){
        std::cout << "Sorry too many hours for August\n";
        std::cout << "Please enter month again";
        std::cin >> userInput;
    } else if (userInput == months [8] && hoursOfMonth > 720){
        std::cout << "Sorry too many hours for September\n";
        std::cout << "Please enter month again";
        std::cin>> userInput;
    } else if (userInput == months[9] && hoursOfMonth > 744){
        std::cout << "Sorry too many hours for October\n";
        std::cout << "Please enter month again";
        std::cin>> userInput;
    } else if (userInput == months[10] && hoursOfMonth > 720) {
        std::cout << "Sorry too many hours for November\n";
        std::cout << "Please enter month again";
        std::cin>> userInput;
    } else if (userInput == months[11] && hoursOfMonth > 744){
        std::cout << "Sorry too many hours for December\n";
        std::cout << "Please enter month again";
        std::cin >> userInput;
    }

    // used to determine how much money would be saved
    if (internetPlan == "A" || internetPlan == "a")
    {
        if (hoursOfMonth <= 10) {
        } else  {
            monthlyBill = internetPlanA + ((hoursOfMonth-10)*2);
            std::cout << "Your bill will be $" << monthlyBill << "\n";
            amountSaved1 = monthlyBill - ((internetPlanB+1*(hoursOfMonth -10)));
            std::cout << "You would save $"<<amountSaved1<< " with internet plan B\n";
            amountSaved2 = monthlyBill - internetPlanC;
            std::cout << "You would save $" <<amountSaved2<< " with internet plan C\n";
        }
    } else if (internetPlan == "B" || internetPlan == "b") {
        if (hoursOfMonth <= 20) {
            monthlyBill = internetPlanB;
            std::cout << "Your monthly bill will be $"<< monthlyBill << "\n";
        } else {
            monthlyBill = internetPlanB + ((hoursOfMonth - 20)*1);
            amountSaved3 = monthlyBill - internetPlanC;
            std::cout << "Your monthly bill will be $"<<monthlyBill << "\n";
            std::cout << "You can save $"<<amountSaved3 << " if you switch to internet plan C\n";
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please try to narrow it down to the relevant code only, the code you actually have trouble with. Or better yet, please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: However, one problem may be that `return` statement in one of the checks. That will cause the program to exit.

Comment: You want to use `&&` not `||`: `internetPlan!= "A" && internetPlan!="a" ...`

Comment: The checks should be written with `while` though, not `if`.

Comment: `return` exits a function. Calling it in  `main` will end your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a good insight on guarding invalid user data. But your code is a bit wrong. Using if clause does not recurse the segment of codes. What you are hoping should be something similar to:

```
while (internetPlan!= "A" && internetPlan!="a" && internetPlan != "B" && internetPlan!= "b" && internetPlan != "C" && internetPlan != "c") {
    std::cout << "Please enter a valid plan\n";
    std::cout << "Enter plan A, B or C\n";
    std::cin >> internetPlan;
}
```

and

```
while (hoursOfMonth < 0 || hoursOfMonth > 744) {
    std::cout << "You cannot have negative hours or more than 744\n";
    std::cout << "Please enter the hours again\n";
    std::cin >> hoursOfMonth;
}
```

Your problem on program exiting should be a consequence of the return statement in second segment. return is used to finish the procedure (with a value), and so int main() is finished and the program terminate.